# Adding Values to a List Separately

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am a beginner to Python and just programming in general so this will probably have a very obvious answer to everyone here.

So - I am currently trying to make hangman however I have run into an issue with the display. I am trying to add underscores to a list, with each underscore being in it's own string. I am doing this with

```
targetWord = ["_ " * len(answer)]
```

answer is the word being searched for

`targetWord` is what the user sees (e.g. app_e)

However instead of adding say, 5 strings with each string containing 1 underscore, 1 string is being added with 5 underscores.

The output is `["_ _ _ _ _ "]`

The output should be `["_ ","_ ","_ ","_ ","_ "]`

All help is appreciated :)

Comment: `targetWord=["_"]*len(answer)`

Comment: You want `['_']*len(answer)`

Comment: Thank you, I will accept the answer asap

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the multiplication outside of the list:

```
targetWord = ["_ " * len(answer)]  # no
targetWord = ["_ "] * len(answer)  # yes
```

Answer (score 1):

You're making the string first and then putting it as a list.

Try

```
targetWord = ['_'] * len(answer)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way to do it:

```
targetWord = 'stackoverflow'

lst = []

for letter in targetWord:
    lst.append('_')

print(lst)

#output

['_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_']
```

Comment: A list comprehension would fit better here, I believe. `lst = ["_" for char in "stackoverflow"]`

Comment: @Coal_ for simplicity?

Comment: Yeah, I personally think this is a prime example of what could be a good one-liner.